# Set a background timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to prevent users in Dynamics 365 / CRM from *quickly* clicking on the same button, thus initiating a synchronous, window-blocking event.
We were able to fix this in IE, but Chrome seems to "remember" the button clicks - and then initiate the same event, again and again, synchronously (as is expected).

I had thought about creating a background timer, that will be initiated on the first button click, which will turn a variable as 'True' until the timer finishes, then turning the variable as 'False'.

During those X seconds in which the variable is set to true, subsequent button clicks will fire the event, but not proceed any further than a few lines where the function will check if the variable is set to true or false.

This is my (not working) code so far:

```
function startTimer(duration) {
isTimerOn = true;
var timer = duration, seconds;
setInterval (function () {
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? 0 + seconds : seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }
}, 500);
isTimerOn = false;
```

};

```
 var isTimerOn = false;

    function createWordSummary() {
        if (isTimerOn) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            startTimer(3);
// Logic here
```

Would love some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
let disabled = false;

function startTimer(s) {
  disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    disabled = false;
  }, s * 1000);
}

function createWordSummary() {
  if ( disabled ) return;
  
  startTimer(3);
  console.log('check');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createWordSummary()">Check</button>
```

Hope it helps!